# c++ - SIGSEGV occurs on exit

Tags: c++, server, gdb, segmentation-fault, gsoap

I'm debugging a server with Eclipse and Multi process GDB. I used gSOAP 2.8 with SSL and WS-Security. The code is basically like this:

```
int main (void)
{
    ServerClass Server;
    ...
    //Configuration of server, SSL and WS-Security
    ...
    if( !Server.valid_socket(Server.bind() ) )
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    while(1)
    {
        if( Server.valid_socket(Server.accept() ) )
        {
            pid_t pid = fork();
            if(!pid)   //Child process
            {
                ...
                Server.serve(); //serves the client
                ...
                Server.destroy(); //ends gsoap connection
                return EXIT_SUCCESS;
            }
            else
            {
                Server.close_socket();
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "Socket invalid" << endl;
    }
    ...
}
```

ServerClass is a class which includes the methods of server and members to configure it. The server processes the client request successfully, returns EXIT_SUCCESS but fails at exit. The debugger shows this trace:

```
Thread[2] 3540 (Suspended : Signal : SIGSEGV: Segmentation Fault)
 - std::ostream::flush() at 0xb7b9c0
 - std::ios_base::Init::~Init() at 0xb7b5d81c   
 - 0xb7918121   
 - exit() at 0xb791817d 
 - __libc_start_main() at 0xb78fea8b    
 - _start() at 0x8143110
```

What could be the problem? Thanks.

---

EDIT: I replaced

```
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
```

for

```
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

The code now works fine, but I haven't idea why fails with return. Any suggestions?

Comment: Guess you'll have to revert your changes until you have a minimal verifiable example.  It looks like some of your libs aren't built with symbols in; and that might help you a little.

Comment: Try Valgrind and rr.